# Selecting the value of output query in sqldf

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sqldf

Selecting the value of output query using sqldf.
This is the output query.

```
  |bill_number|
```

|0|       |3768|

|1|       |3769|

|2|       |3770|

|3|       |3771|

|4|       |3772|

|...|      |...|

|58|      |3842|

|59|      |3843|

|60|      |3844|

|61|      |3846|

|62|      |3847|

I want to use all of these values in another query. How can I get these values and put it into a variable?

Comment: `I want to use all of this values to another query` I'm not clear what you mean by this. Do you mean want to _make a new query_ using the values from this query?

Comment: yes. sorry for the unclear question.